# EF query won't cast

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am using EF 4.x to populate an ASP.NET dropdown list. I first create a variable:

```
CPAS_EM.qryxrefVendorWorker wrkrs;
```

Then, I go to populate it:

```
        using (CPASEntities sds = new CPASEntities())
        {
            wrkrs = (qryxrefVendorWorker)
                (from w in sds.qryxrefVendorWorkers 
                 where w.VendorID == currVendorID && 
                 ((w.ExpiryDate == null) | (w.ExpiryDate >= currWorkDate)) 
                 select w);
            ddlWorker.DataSource = wrkrs;
            ddlWorker.DataValueField = wrkrs.WorkerID.ToString();
            ddlWorker.DataTextField = wrkrs.WorkerName;
            ddlWorker.DataBind();
        }
```

I'm getting an error on the "wrkrs = ..." statement indicating a casting error:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[CPAS_EM.qryxrefVendorWorker]' to
>   type 'CPAS_EM.qryxrefVendorWorker'

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 4):

Your code

```
(from w in sds.qryxrefVendorWorkers 
where w.VendorID == currVendorID && ((w.ExpiryDate == null) | (w.ExpiryDate >= currWorkDate)) 
select w)
```

is actually a query, not a single object. You probably want to add `FirstOrDefault()` to just get a single element. Then there's also no cast necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the variable declared outside of the using scope? Can't you do:

```
   using (CPASEntities sds = new CPASEntities())
    {
        var wrkrs = (from w in sds.qryxrefVendorWorkers 
                     where w.VendorID == currVendorID 
                       && ((w.ExpiryDate == null) | (w.ExpiryDate >= currWorkDate)) 
                     select w).FirstOrDefault();
        ddlWorker.DataSource = wrkrs;
        ddlWorker.DataValueField = wrkrs.WorkerID.ToString();
        ddlWorker.DataTextField = wrkrs.WorkerName;
        ddlWorker.DataBind();
    }
```

and eliminate the declaration altogether?

Also, as user1908061 said, you also need the FirstOrDefault() to get just a single object instead of a collection.

Comment: Seems to be my problem. I want the query to return a set of "qryxrefVendorWorkers", not a single object. It seems I need some sort of Iqueryiable object?

Comment: Also, the reason it's declared outside the using block is to make it available to the ASP.NET page as the datasource for the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
List<sds.qryxrefVendorWorkers > lstWorkers = 
    (from w in sds.qryxrefVendorWorkers 
     where w.VendorID == currVendorID && 
     ((w.ExpiryDate == null) | (w.ExpiryDate >= currWorkDate)) 
     select w).ToList();


ddlWorker.DataSource = lstWorkers;
ddlWorker.DataValueField = "WorkerID";
ddlWorker.DataTextField = "WorkerName";
ddlWorker.DataBind();
```

This will return a set of `qryxrefVendorWorkers`.
The casting failed because (in simple terms) you tried to cast a set of objects into a single object when you cast the query into a `qryxrefVendorWorker`